# How to get image name from imageview

Tags: android

I have an imageview which has an image loaded in it. This way

```
// create bitmap from resource
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.profile_blank_xlarge);

// set circle bitmap
ImageView mImage = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
mImage.setImageBitmap(getCircleBitmap(bm));
```

I want to be able to find out the name of the image in the `ImageView` once the application is run.

I tried doing `mImage.getTag()` to get the name of the image in the `ImageView` but it crashes my app. 
What is the correct way to get the name of the image in a `ImageView`

**Crash Details**

```
  --------- beginning of crash
07-02 13:11:37.259    2096-2096/com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample, PID: 2096
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample/com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.kmi_dev.fbloginsample.MyAccount.onCreateView(MyAccount.java:115)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6005)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: The author means the NAME of the image that is used as source for the ImageView, not the name of the ImageView. Read more carefull

Comment: You need to set name of the Image as tag to ImageView first using `.setTag()` function and and then call `.getTag()` method.

Comment: It is crashing because there is no tag set. As your crash report says there is a null. Android doc says: `getTag()` returns the Object stored in this view as a tag, or null if not set

Comment: @Rick Roy, please add some more codes....